# De Morgan's law on a boolean expression

Tags: boolean-expression, demorgans-law

The question is:
Assume that `p`, `q` and `r` are boolean variables. Consider the following expression:

```
!(p && !q || r)
Which of the following expressions is equivalent to the given expression?
A. (p && r) || (!q && r)
B. (!p && !q) || (!p && r)
C. (!p || q ) && !r
D. (!p || q && !r)
E. (!p || q) || r
```

I solved it as D. But the answer is C. What the law of associativity for boolean operators?
Can anyone explain why it should be C?

Thanks,
Mita

Comment: See [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). The associativity is all leftward, and precedence is: `(), !, &&/||`

Comment: You could write a little program that tests all 8 inputs for all alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

Boolean algebra uses this operator precedence: NOT, AND, OR

So the original expression can be rewritten as:

```
!((p && !q) || r)
  ^--     ^-- new
```

without changing meaning. To preserve that order of operations after the negation:

```
!(p && !q) && !r
(!p || q) && !r
```

which is your C) answer

Answer (score 1):

See [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and note that it is only directly defined over `(P && Q)` and `(P || Q)`.

The binary operators are [left-associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) and [precedence is: `(), !, &&, ||`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence).

Thus:

```
!(p && !q || r)      // start
!((p && !q) || r)    // explicitly grouping by precedence
(!(p && !q) && !r)   // by DM
(!p || q) && !r      // by DM
```

This arrives at `C`, but we can't get do `D` because that would require [distributing over `&&`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) or adjusting the parenthesis such that the precedence is changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I confused leftward as starting from the leftmost operand. So left associativity means starting with the rightmost operand and going left?

Comment: @user3096748 [Leftward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) means that, for the same precedence, `a || b || c || d` is equivalent to `((a || b) || c) || d` - or "the operations are grouped from the left". However, the precedence rules apply first (`&&` has a higher precedence than `||`). I fixed my initial inline comment which incorrectly stated adding the parenthesis was equivalent by associativity - when in fact it is equivalent due to precedence.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a good site which I can reference for laws of association etc for boolean and relational operators?

Comment: @user3096748 I usually start at Wikipedia .. it's not the best, but it has a little bit on a lot of stuff (have 3 different links in the answer now ;-) It's been awhile since I've really dug into this on course work.

Comment: So if its !(p || !q && r) this is then !(p || (!q && r)) = !p && !(!q && r) = !p && (q || !r) ?

Comment: @user3096748 Yes, `&&` has a higher precedence so the initial grouping is correct.

Comment: @user3096748 As mchfrnc said in another answer, a TTL can be used to verify equivalence which can be a good way to double-check an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer using [PyEDA](https://github.com/cjdrake/pyeda)

```
>>> from pyeda.inter import *
>>> f = Not(Or(And('p', '-q'), 'r'))
>>> ga = Or(And('p', 'r'), And('-q', 'r'))
>>> gb = Or(And('-p', '-q'), And('-p', 'r'))
>>> gc = And(Or('-p', 'q'), '-r')
>>> gd = Or('-p', And('q', '-r'))
>>> ge = Or(Or('-p', 'q'), 'r')

>>> for g in [ga, gb, gc, gd, ge]:
...     print(f.equivalent(g))

False
False
True
False
False

>>> expr2truthtable(f)
inputs: r q p
000 1
001 0
010 1
011 1
100 0
101 0
110 0
111 0

>>> expr2truthtable(gc)
inputs: r q p
000 1
001 0
010 1
011 1
100 0
101 0
110 0
111 0
```